# How to print an image on Zebra Card printer from Java

Tags: java, printing, zebra-printers

I would like to print an image on a zebra card printer from java, the image is of the correct card size. But I would like to know how to position it on the card, so that there will be no margins and it will be printed as if it is being printed from a normal word file, or an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I printed it using java without any zebra libraries.
but i had to change the pageformat using this way:

```
        PageFormat defaultPage = printJob.defaultPage();

        Paper x = new Paper();
        x.setImageableArea(0, 0, height, width);
        x.setSize(height, width);
        defaultPage.setPaper(x);
        PageFormat pageFormat = defaultPage;
        printJob.setPrintable(this, pageFormat);
```

the trick was to make a new paper not modify the paper taken from the pageformat.